# javascript Multiple space into input value self trim

Tags: javascript, html, input, space, trim

I have an input like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myName" value="John Fitzgerald          Kennedy      " />
```

When I read the input content using Javascript:

```
var myName = document.getElementsByName("myName")[0].value;
```

The content of myName: `"John Fitzgerald Kennedy "`;

How to have the content: `"John Fitzgerald          Kennedy         "`?

I have to count the fixed chars between name and surname to find the surname and split correctly two separate strings.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, it doesn't do that for me ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/81Lxzjqw/)). Anything else happening on your page?

Comment: I'm sorry but your example help me so much to find the error: in the string of the input I have an entity like &#39; so the error is in the substr count because the input is a fixed size text but the entity use 5 of the positions and move the second part of the name on the left. how to take the input with an entity without convert it?

Comment: Show an example that reproduces your actual content, show precisely what result you want/need, and then I'll try my best to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this may help. Try replacing spaces within the string with a single `' '` character and trimming whitespace from the beginning and end of the string like this:

```
var myName = document.getElementsByName("myName")[0].value.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim();
```

After that you can parse the string to extract the given name and surname like this

```
var surname = myName.substring(myName.lastIndexOf(' '));
var givenName = myName.substring(0, myName.lastIndexOf(' '));
```

This link is helpful for learning about string operations: [W3C String Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You have content with multiple spaces. But if you want see it in HTML node like `div` you need to replace spaces with `&nbsp;`. But in `<pre>` tag you don't need in replacement.

http://jsfiddle.net/ha9pt60v/4/

```
// myName is "John Fitzgerald          Kennedy      "
var myName = document.getElementsByName("myName")[0].value;

// in <pre>
document.getElementById('pre').innerHTML = myName;

// in another tag
document.getElementById('my').innerHTML = myName.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');
```

Comment: But it's in the value of an `<input />`, which does not collapse white-space (in general, for most HTML elements, you're right; but not in this context, unless I'm really mis-reading your answer?)

Comment: @DavidThomas, asker said that he lost spaces when read by `document.getElementsByName("myName")[0].value`. And I thought that he just printed it in HTML element and cannot see multiple spaces.